# Bind outside variable and in Class protected field with method param

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

How to implement this kind of functionality:

- Fill entity eg. `Member` with data
- Bind `Member` to form with `$form->bind($member)` to private property `_formData`
- Afterward do some stuff inside $form, eg. `$form->validate()` with `_formData`
- `$member` should be also changed as `_formData` is changed.

  ```
  class Form {

      private $_formData;

      function bind1(&$row) {
          // this change member outside
          $row['full_name'] =
              $row['first_name']
              . ' ' .
              $row['last_name'];
      }

      function bind2(&$row) {
          $this->_formData = $row;
          // this will not change memeber
          $this->_formData['full_name'] =
              $this->_formData['first_name']
              . ' '
              . $this->_formData['last_name'];
      }
  }

  $member = array('full_name' => null, 'first_name'=>'Fn', 'last_name' => 'Ln');
  $form = new Form();

  $form->bind1($member);
  var_dump($member['full_name']);
  // output: 'FnLn'

  $form->bind2($member);
  var_dump($member['full_name']);
  // output: null
  ```

Method `validate` work with private _fieldData, so this to work bind2 test should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible, but you need to set a reference of the reference in the bind1 and bind2 method, like this:

```
$this->_formData = & $row;
```

You are also making misspellings between `full_name` and `fullName` as array keys. For example in the `bind2` method:

```
$this->_formData['full_name'] =  $this->_formData['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->_formData['last_name'];
```

And in your test-code you var_dump `full_name`. Chaging `full_name` in `bind2` to `fullName` should fix your issue.

Comment: yep! `$this->_formData = &$row;` solved. Assigning private _formData with pass by reference **also** **&**$row is solution that worked. Wanted to self-answer but this way is nicer :) Other part is not important (misspelling) - just test code.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are assigning the full_name key of your member variable and trying to access fullName variable so it is returning NULL

Comment: Sorry about that. This part was just misspelled in question code. You are right about `null`, thanx.